# Using Rsync include and exclude options to include directory and file by pattern

Tags: linux, unix, rsync, darwin

I'm having problems getting my `rsync` syntax right and I'm wondering if my scenario can actually be handled with `rsync`. First, I've confirmed that `rsync` is working just fine between my local host and my remote host. Doing a straight sync on a directory is successful.

Here's what my filesystem looks like:

```
uploads/
  1260000000/
    file_11_00.jpg
    file_11_01.jpg
    file_12_00.jpg
  1270000000/
    file_11_00.jpg
    file_11_01.jpg
    file_12_00.jpg
  1280000000/
    file_11_00.jpg
    file_11_01.jpg
    file_12_00.jpg
```

What I want to do is run rsync only on files that begin with "file_11_" in the subdirectories and I want to be able to run just one rsync job to sync all of these files in the subdirectories.

Here's the command that I'm trying:

`rsync -nrv --include="**/file_11*.jpg" --exclude="*" /Storage/uploads/ /website/uploads/`

This results in `0` files being marked for transfer in my dry run. I've tried various other combinations of `--include` and `--exclude` statements, but either continued to get no results or got everything as if no include or exclude options were set.

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The problem is that `--exclude="*"` says to exclude (for example) the `1260000000/` directory, so `rsync` never examines the contents of that directory, so never notices that the directory contains files that would have been matched by your `--include`.

I think the closest thing to what you want is this:

```
rsync -nrv --include="*/" --include="file_11*.jpg" --exclude="*" /Storage/uploads/ /website/uploads/
```

(which will include all directories, and all files matching `file_11*.jpg`, but no other files), or *maybe* this:

```
rsync -nrv --include="/[0-9][0-9][0-9]0000000/" --include="file_11*.jpg" --exclude="*" /Storage/uploads/ /website/uploads/
```

(same concept, but much pickier about the directories it will include).

In either case, note that the `--include=...` option needs to come *before* the `--exclude=...` option, because we need the former to take precedence over the latter when a file matches both patterns.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed. My scenario was actually more or less what you described in your second example, but I kept my question simplified to make the question more straight forward.

Comment: Note the importance of (e.g.) `--include="*/"` in including the **parent** directories of the files you actually want to include.

Comment: Note the order of arguments: `--include` has to come before `--exclude`

Comment: @hfs Yeah, I feel that this should be mentioned in the actual answer. I was trying to do something similar before finding this page, and knew that I needed the `-include="*/"`, yet it still didn't work. Looking at this answer my first thought was "that's exactly what I'm doing!". Then I noticed the order was different.

Comment: Another key concept is that "when using the --recursive (-r) option (which is implied by -a), every subcomponent of  every path is visited from the top down, so include/exclude patterns get applied recursively to each subcomponent's full name"

Comment: For some odd reason this doesn't work in my case. I only want to copy some directories and all files in them with the subdirectories. I have the directory list in a file and use `--include-from=name-fo-file`. If I include the `--include="*/"` in the biginning, it copies everything. If I don't, it copies only the empty "included" directories. I'm puzzled.

Comment: `rsync`'s implementation of `include` and `exclude` is so incredibly unintuitive. Why should ordering of the command switches matter? Why wouldn't every file be considered? If `include` is specified alone, why wouldn't it assume that everything else is excluded? It's not even remotely close to how I would have approached this problem.

Answer (score 83):

`rsync` include exclude pattern examples:

```
"*"         means everything
"dir1"      transfers empty directory [dir1]
"dir*"      transfers empty directories like: "dir1", "dir2", "dir3", etc...
"file*"     transfers files whose names start with [file]
"dir**"     transfers every path that starts with [dir] like "dir1/file.txt", "dir2/bar/ffaa.html", etc...
"dir***"    same as above
"dir1/*"    does nothing
"dir1/**"   does nothing
"dir1/***"  transfers [dir1] directory and all its contents like "dir1/file.txt", "dir1/fooo.sh", "dir1/fold/baar.py", etc...
```

And final note is that simply dont rely on asterisks that are used in the beginning for evaluating paths; like `"**dir"` (its ok to use them for single folders or files but not paths) and note that more than two asterisks dont work for file names.

Comment: Your answer is the only one which is usable because you explain the general behaving. The other answers are too specific according the OP but each situation needs another solution! It helped me a lot!

Comment: A thorough yet not as intuitive explanation can be found on the `rsync` manpage in section `INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES`

Answer (score 28):

Here's my "teach a person to fish" answer:

Rsync's syntax is definitely non-intuitive, but it is worth understanding.

1. First, use `-vvv` to see the debug info for rsync.

```sh
$ rsync -nr -vvv --include="**/file_11*.jpg" --exclude="*" /Storage/uploads/ /website/uploads/

[sender] hiding directory 1280000000 because of pattern *
[sender] hiding directory 1260000000 because of pattern *
[sender] hiding directory 1270000000 because of pattern *
```

The key concept here is that rsync applies the include/exclude patterns for each directory recursively. As soon as the first include/exclude is matched, the processing stops.

The first directory it evaluates is `/Storage/uploads`. `Storage/uploads` has `1280000000/, 1260000000/, 1270000000/` dirs/files. None of them match `file_11*.jpg` to include. All of them match `*` to exclude. So they are excluded, and rsync ends.

2. The solution is to include all dirs (`*/`) first. Then the first dir component will be `1260000000/, 1270000000/, 1280000000/` since they match `*/`. The next dir component will be `1260000000/`. In `1260000000/`, `file_11_00.jpg` matches `--include="file_11*.jpg"`, so it is included. And so forth.

```sh
$ rsync -nrv --include='*/' --include="file_11*.jpg" --exclude="*" /Storage/uploads/ /website/uploads/

./
1260000000/
1260000000/file_11_00.jpg
1260000000/file_11_01.jpg
1270000000/
1270000000/file_11_00.jpg
1270000000/file_11_01.jpg
1280000000/
1280000000/file_11_00.jpg
1280000000/file_11_01.jpg
```

https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1

Comment: if you're always typing `--include='*/'`, that probably indicates room for improvement in the interface.