# How to scp all .txt files under a parent directory, together with the sub-directories, from a server?

Tags: rsync, scp, subdirectory

I have a directory (let's call it `master`) on a server.

Under the directory `master`, there're many `.txt` files; some `.txt` files are under sub-directories in `master`, say

```
    /master/text1.txt
    /master/sub-dir1/text2.txt
    /master/sub-dir2/sub-dir3/text3.txt
```

There are also a big number of other types of files in the `master`.

What I want to do is to `scp` all the `.txt` files under `master` to my local, and retain the sub-directory structure, i.e. the result looks like

```
    /local-dir/text1.txt
    /local-dir/sub-dir1/text2.txt
    /local-dir/sub-dir2/sub-dir3/text3.txt
```

How can I get this done?

Answer (score -1):

If you need to keep the folder structure, you can try with rsync. Here is an answer you might want to look at: [Using Rsync include and exclude options to include directory and file by pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952000/using-rsync-include-and-exclude-options-to-include-directory-and-file-by-pattern)

I copied the answer below for your reference:

> I think the closest thing to what you want is this:
>
> rsync -nrv --include="*/" --include="file_11*.jpg" --exclude="*" /Storage/uploads/ /website/uploads/
>
> (which will include all directories, and all files matching file_11*.jpg, but no other files), or maybe this:
>
> rsync -nrv --include="/[0-9][0-9][0-9]0000000/" --include="file_11*.jpg" --exclude="*" /Storage/uploads/ /website/uploads/
>
> (same concept, but much pickier about the directories it will include).

You can easily update the command to only include the `.txt` files.